# The PDF/CDF of the Nearest Neighbor to the Nearest Neighbor of the origin (HPPP)

Tags: statistics, stationary-processes

Is there a well-known PDF/CDF of the Nearest Neighbor to the Nearest Neighbor of the origin. Specifically, assume we have a homogeneous Poisson Point Process (HPPP), $\Phi\in\mathbb{R}^2$. For the ease of exposition, let $X$ be the nearest point to the origin, and $Y$ as the nearest point to X, where $X,Y \in \Phi$. Then, what's the PDF/CDF of the distance between X and Y?

If there's no well-known PDF/CDF, can you kindly advise me the steps to obtain them. So far, I only know the PDF and CDF of the distance between X and the origin.

Comment: What does "H" in "HPPP" mean here?

Comment: Homogeneous Poisson Point Process?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am referring to homogeneous Point Point Process. I have edited the details.

Comment: I would assume $P(\|X-Y\|\le t)$ is something like $1-\exp(-cA(t))$ where $A(t)$ is the area of the disk of radius $t$ centered at $X$ intersect the complement of the disk of radius $\|X\|$ centered at $0$.  I suppose there is a simple trigonometric formula for this area: it is the area of a disk minus the areas of two chordal regions.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks. I'm currently trying this approach. Will update once it is solved.

Comment: @kimchilover Given $\left\Vert X \right\Vert$, I have obtained the conditional CDF of $\mathbb{P}\left( \left\Vert X-Y \right\Vert \leq t\right)$. To obtain this conditional CDF, I have computed the area $A\left( t \right)$ which is a piecewise function. But how can I further get the unconditional CDF? My idea is to take integrate with the pdf of ∥X∥.

Comment: That's the plan.  The pdf of $\|X\|$ is something like $f(r)=2\lambda\pi r \exp(-\lambda\pi r^2)$, which may or may not leave you with a calculus puzzle.